# Handling User Control Events on Containing Page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to have a user control containing a save button.

I want the click event attached to the save button to be handled by the containing page not the user control

Is this possible?

EDIT MORE SPECIFIC

Say I have a page called "Editor Page" and a user control called "Editor Buttons". 
On the "Editor Buttons" user control I have a save button (which is a web control). I want the Click event of the save button to be handled by the "Editor Page" rather than the user control.

The reason for this is because I want to specify base pages that implement common behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that you have the code for the UserControl. If that is the case, you can define a Save event in your user control and have it expose the Click event of the save button, [either directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943171/expose-and-raise-event-of-a-child-control-in-a-usercontrol-in-c/943192#943192), or by internally setting up an event handler and raise the Save event when the button is clicked. That could look something like this in the UserControl:

```
public event EventHandler Save;

private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnSave(e);
}

protected void OnSave(EventArgs e)
{
    // raise the Save event
    EventHandler save = Save;
    if (save != null)
    {
        save(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This technique is commonly referred to as “event bubbling”.

Here is an exmple:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl

{

 public event EventHandler buttonClick;

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     buttonClick(sender, e);
 }

}
```

Then you can subscribe the event buttonClick at webpage to display the different information .

```
public partial class Test: System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 UserControlID.buttonClick+=new EventHandler(UserControlID_buttonClick);

}

protected void UserControlID_buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Write("hello,I am jack.");
 }

}
```

Comment: What if the UserControl that needs to pass the event to the holding page is one of many types of dynamically rendered UserControl

Answer (score 1):

UserControl1.ascx

UserControl1.ascx.cs

public partial class UserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl

{

```
public event EventHandler UserControl1Click;



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

}



protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    UserControl1Click(sender, e);

}
```

}

UserControl2.ascx

UserControl1.ascx.cs

public partial class UserControl2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl

{

```
public event EventHandler UserControl2Click;



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

} 




protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    UserControl2Click(sender, e);

}
```

}

Then add one Asp.Net Text box(to display user control id) and above two user controls to Aspx page as shown below.

```
<title>Untitled Page</title>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">



<div>



<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />



<UC1:UC ID="uc1" runat="server" />



<UC1:UC ID="uc2" runat="server" />



</div>



</form>
```

Now add event handler for each user control to handle button click event of two controls as shown below.

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    uc1.UserControl1Click += new EventHandler(uc1_UserControl1Click);

    uc2.UserControl2Click += new EventHandler(uc2_UserControl2Click);

}



protected void uc1_UserControl1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    txt1.Text = "User Control 1 Clicked";

}



protected void uc2_UserControl2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    txt1.Text = "User Control 2 Clicked";

}
```

}

If we click User Control1, text box displays “User Control 1 Clicked” or if we click on User Control2, text box displays “User Control 2 Clicked”.