# create custom events in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a control in vb.net. Now I want that control to send some message(fire an event called recieve) and the parent application that implements it will have to create an even listener called recieve and do actions accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you question is?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080808/how-to-expose-and-raise-custom-events-for-a-vb-net-winforms-user-control

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Public Custom Event recieve As EventHandler

    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        _handlers.Add(value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        If _handlers.Contains(value) Then
            _handlers.Remove(value)
        End If
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        For Each handler As EventHandler In _handlers
            Try
                handler.Invoke(sender, e)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception while invoking event handler: " & ex.ToString())
            End Try
        Next
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

Then you may raise the event by typing

```
Dim raise As New System.EventArgs
RaiseEvent recieve(sender, raise)
```

anywhere in your code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use thge single line `Public Event recieve As EventHandler` and achieve the same effect as all that code minus the exception handling.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food can you explain that?

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar, see my separate answer.

Comment: What variable is `_handlers`?

Answer (score 11):

This code will do the same thing as @user1057768's answer with a lot less fuss.  Any exceptions thrown by an event handler will come back through the `OnReceive` method, so you can catch them there or elsewhere in your class.

```
Class MyClass
    Public Event Recieve As EventHandler 

    Protected Overridable Sub OnReceive(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Receive(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You only need to use a `Custom Event` if you need special code to handle or raise the event.

Answer (score 4):

In your control class you must declare a public event

```
Class MyControl

    Public Event MyReceivedEvent(ByVal AParameterIWantToSend As TheTypeOfThisParameter, ByVal AnotherParmeter As AnotherType, ...)

    ...

End Class
```

And when you use your control, you might hook the event in the xaml

```
< MyControl x:Name="MyControlName" MyReceivedEvent="AHandlerForThisEvent" ...  />
```

Or in the code :

```
AddHandler MyControlName.MyReceivedEvent, AddressOf AHandlerForThisEvent
```

Rq 1 : Your event might have no parameters.
Rq2 : The handler can have the same parameters, or less if you don't care about some of them. It is a good habit to get them all.
Rq3 : you might use Delegates to have a cleaner code, and warning/errors if you don't respect the Event's signature. like in

```
Public Delegate Sub MyReceivedHandler(ByVal NumberOfItemsReceived As Integer, ByVal QualityOfReception As String, ByRef ReceptionHandled As Boolean)
```

and then you hook your handler with

```
AddHandler MyControlName.MyReceivedEvent, New MyReveivedHandler(AddressOf AHandlerForThisEvent)
```

If you declared your event with this Delegate Type, the listeners will have to respect the EventHandler signature.

```
Public Event MyReceivedEvent As MyReceivedHandler
```

Rq4 : You might use ByRef parameters, just as in the latest example, so the parameter is sent to a listener, can be changed, and the next listener sees the updated value of this parameter.

Rq5 : you might use lambda as Event listener, in simple scenarios, like

```
AddHandler MyControlName.MyReceivedEvent, _
             New MyReceivedHandler(Sub(ByVal num As Integer , ByVal Q As String, ByRef RHandled As Boolean) _
                           MessageBox.Show(" Message receiveived  containing " & num & " items " & " of Quality : " & Q )
```