# Writing layer to a class?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a Class that contains: A DataGrid, A Pager

I am trying to make User Control that contains both of them and have all property that links to both of them.

So something:

```
public class MyGridViewPager : ltcGrid
    {
        public GridView aGridView;
        public DataPager aDataPager;
        public bool AutoGenerateColumns { 
           get { return this.aGridView.AutoGenerateColumns; } 
           set { this.aGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = value; } }

}
```

So I can use the property from them in my MyGridViewPager UserControl and in case of any choice change on the GridView or DataPager I can modify only the layer...or is it called wrapper-class? Not so sure about the naming...

But... how do I do the same thing for EventHandler?
I can see it defines in:

```
public delegate void SelectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e);
```

How can I expose this handler from my user control?

Note: I don't really want to do MyGridViewPager.aGridView.SelectionChangedEventArgs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a myriad of ways to do this:

- [Exposing events of underlying control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943171/expose-and-raise-event-of-a-child-control-in-a-usercontrol-in-c)
- [Event Bubbling in C#](http://odetocode.com/Articles/94.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want to do!