# Exposing OnclientClick function in user control asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [expose and raise event of a child control in a usercontrol in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943171/expose-and-raise-event-of-a-child-control-in-a-usercontrol-in-c-sharp)

I have user control with one html input button.

On page I am consuming that user control. How can I expose onclient event of that input button inside user control so if that button client so i can call page function.

```
<uc2:UC_LayoutSelector ID="UC_LayoutSelector1" runat="server" OnClientLayoutSelect="UC_LayoutSelector1_MyPageFunction" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

        function UC_LayoutSelector1_MyPageFunction(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: make a property and get and set it with viewstate

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may just want to create a public property of the onclient property of the input button. If you are trying to capture the moment when the user clicks that button, you will want to cause a postback with the javascript function and raise the event control programmatically. That will allow you to trap the event on the parent page.